# How can I avoid that cp freezes my OS?

Tags: linux, freeze, cp

I am using `cp` to copy data like so:

```
cp -r from_here to_there
```

When I do that, my computer freezes and unfreezes periodically. I have 4 CPUs installed and the HD is connected via SATA. `from_here` and `to_there` are both on the same file system so no network is used. The freezing is somehow dependent on the amount of files being copied. For a lot of files it is even impossible to sign in on the machine via ssh.

Is there a way to check why my OS freezes and unfreezes? Can I maybe tell `cp` to take it easy somehow?

Comment: You can use `nice cp [arguments]` (for CPU) or `ionice cp [arguments]` (for disk IO, on some systems), but that won't eliminate the root of your problems I guess ([more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)))

Comment: Is there a way to lower process priority (sorry, not a linux guy)

Comment: @slhck for `ionice cp -r from_here to_there` i get: `none: prio 4
ionice: cannot parse number 'cp'`. For `nice cp -r 24 24m` it simply starts copying and I do not get any feedback...

Comment: try renicing the process once it's started.

Comment: I just found out, that the process has a priority of 20. So it cannot get any lower than that.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what version of kernel you are using. There was a bug in the kernel causing the machine to be unresponsive under I/O stress.

If you have a recent-enough kernel, just using `ionice` should be enough. I'm using `ionice` in conjunction with `screen` for background downloading and it works great (no impact on machine responsiveness).

`screen -d -m ionice -c 3 io_heavy_cmd`

Comment: I gave your recommendation a try and at first sight it seems to not block my computer anymore. I'll test this a little more until I accept the answer^^